# Displaying a different values every X seconds using React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display "Orange" for 2 seconds, "Kiwi" or 1 second and "Mango" for 3 seconds. Here's my attempt which is displaying a still "Orange: 2000" while I am expecting it to flip based on the number of specified seconds. What am I missing?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const IntervalExample = () => {
    const fruits = [
        {id: 1, name: "Orange", duration: 2000},
        {id: 2, name: "Kiwi", duration: 1000},
        {id: 3, name: "Mango", duration: 3000},
    ]

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [currentFruit, setCurrentFruit] = useState(fruits[index]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setIndex(index === fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1)
            setCurrentFruit(fruits[index])
        }, currentFruit.duration);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                {currentFruit.name}: {currentFruit.duration}
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};

export default IntervalExample;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your component  driven by its states when the index is changed it triggers a useEffect hook that updates the currentFruit state, currentFruit change triggers another useEffect that updates the index and so on, then just use `setTimeout` like :

```
const IntervalExample = () => {
    const fruits = [
        {id: 1, name: "Orange", duration: 2000},
        {id: 2, name: "Kiwi", duration: 1000},
        {id: 3, name: "Mango", duration: 3000},
    ]

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [currentFruit, setCurrentFruit] = useState(fruits[index]);

   
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentFruit(fruits[index])
    }, [index])

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setTimeout(() => {
            setIndex(index === fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1)       
        }, currentFruit.duration);
    }, [currentFruit])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                {currentFruit.name}: {currentFruit.duration}
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't you cleanup your intervals in the useEffect?

Comment: it's just a `setTimeout` which doesn't need a clear

Answer (score 1):

UseEffect just be called only one time. So, `Const interval` will init a closure for function call for time interval. It will be never change. Index in closure will be always 0.

Here is my solution, just use one state for index:

```
const IntervalExample = () => {
    const fruits = [
        {id: 1, name: "Orange", duration: 2000},
        {id: 2, name: "Kiwi", duration: 1000},
        {id: 3, name: "Mango", duration: 3000},
    ]

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    //because fruit depend on index. Dont need a separate state
    const currentFruit = fruits[index];

    const handleIndex = () => {
        setIndex(index === fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        //after render current fruit. We new timeout to set next fruit.
        setTimeout(handleIndex, currentFruit.duration);
    }, [index]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                {currentFruit.name}: {currentFruit.duration}
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different timeouts for each fruit, then `setTimeout` will be the better approach.

Since `setInterval` is being called in `useEffect` the initial value will be set as the interval to change the displayed fruit information.

The problem in your code was while updating the `index` in the state it's not getting updated properly.

In order to solve that instead of directly updating the value, I'm using updated state value like below

```
setIndex((index) => (index === fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1))
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const fruits = [
  { id: 1, name: "Orange", duration: 2000 },
  { id: 2, name: "Kiwi", duration: 1000 },
  { id: 3, name: "Mango", duration: 3000 }
];

const IntervalExample = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentFruit, setCurrentFruit] = useState(fruits[0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex((index) => (index === fruits.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1));
    }, fruits[index].duration);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentFruit(fruits[index]);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {currentFruit.name}: {currentFruit.duration}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(
       <IntervalExample />,
       document.getElementById("root")
     );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```